# How many views can be bound to a 2D texture at a time?

Tags: directx11

I am a newbie trying to learn on DX11.x. While reading about resources and views in MSDN, I thought this question 
For a given 2D Texture created with `ID3D11Texture2D`interface (or for that matter any kind of resource), how many of following views can be bound to it?

1) DepthStencilView
 2) RenderTargetView
 3) ShaderResourceView
 4) UnorderedAccessView

Thanks in advance.
PS: I know the answer would be app specific, but still any insight into this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API-imposed limit on the number of views of a single texture you can create.  Views are just a way to access the same texture data in different ways, interpreting it as different formats or referring to different mip levels and so forth.  They're very lightweight objects.

Comment: Can a resource have render target and depth stencil view bound to it at the same time?

Comment: @Recker I'm not sure.  The resource would have to be created with bind flags for both render target and depth-stencil, and I'm not sure if D3D11 will accept that.  If it does, you could create both render target and depth-stencil views for the same texture, but you could not have them both bound to the pipeline at once.

Comment: No, a resource can not be a render and depth-stencil target simultaneously,  due to the pixel format. A depth target needs to have a `DXGI_FORMAT_D[N]_...` format (being `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` the most common when using stencil, `DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT` otherwise), and the render target needs a `DXGI_FORMAT_R[N]G[N]B[N]A[N]`, being `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` the most common.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira You can use typeless formats to alias a depth buffer as a texture for reading it in the shader (e.g. `D32_FLOAT` and `R32_FLOAT`), so it's not obvious to me that you wouldn't be able to alias it as a render target as well.  It may still not be allowed, but I don't think pixel formats are the reason.

Comment: According to msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173059(v=vs.85).aspx), there is no such type that match something like R[N]G[N]B[N]A[N]_X[M]X[P] and X[N*4]_D[M]S[P], so, they may not be the reason, but for the same reason, that type does not exist.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I don't understand what you're saying in that last comment, but like I said, you can certainly make a texture with a `D32_FLOAT` DSV and an `R32_FLOAT` SRV, and you can certainly also render to `R32_FLOAT`.  So the types do work out.  But without trying it, I don't know whether a single texture can be used both as `D32_FLOAT` DSV and `R32_FLOAT` RTV.

Comment: No, it can't, since it will be overlapped with both texture and depth data, that's what I was trying to say. There is no pixel type big enough to fit AND to *align* both together.